# Hiding/Editing e-mail headers

Tags: linux, email, email-server, exim

```
from 1.2.3.4-rDNS ([1.2.3.4]:57306 helo=[127.0.0.1]) by SERVERHOSTNAME with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:256) (Exim 4.80) (envelope-from <MYEMAIL>) id 1ZGFeS-0023uH-H1 for MYEMAIL; Sun, 01 Mar 2013 19:53:12 -0500
```

Is there a way to hide the hostname or is that not possible?

I am trying to make my server whitelable friendly and would like to hide the hostname.

I have WHM/Cpanel on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will always be **something** as hostname, though you could configure it to show something other than the actual hostname. This is however a bad idea since it's more likely to get your mail tagged as spam by lots of antispam software.

I have no idea what you mean with "whitelable friendly".

Comment: people who resell. so client dont see our host name and know they resell.

Comment: I don't understand how having a complete hostname in the headers will be an indication of reselling (resale?). However, very few humans ever look at the headers; when they do, it's usually to verify whether an email is spam or not, whether it comes from the person it looks like coming from or not. Mostly the headers are used by mailservers and spamfilters that do automatic parsing of them. You could always get a second domain with an innocuous name and place the sending mailserver in that one, I suppose, but **do** make it a real host name if you want the mail to get through!